¿Cómo puedo escribir una función que verifique caracteres?
Antes de comenzar, gracias por su ayuda, estoy comenzando con la programación, y se me ha planteado el siguiente problema:
Quiero escribir una función que verifique si dos caracteres dados son del mismo tipo, es decir, si alguno de los caracteres no es una letra,(dos números o un número y una letra), devuelve: -1.
Si ambos caracteres son del mismo tipo,(dos letras minúsculas o dos letras mayúsculas),devuelve: 1.
Si ambos caracteres son letras, pero no el mismo caso,( una minúscula y una mayúscula), devuelve: 0
He escrito este código, y la segunda y tercera premisa si se cumplen pero no la primera:
a = input('Introduzca un caracter cualquiera: ')
b = input('Introduzca otro caracter cualquiera: ')

if a == (a.lower()) and b == (b.lower()):
    print(1) 
elif a == (a.isupper()) and b == (b.isupper()):
    print(1)
elif a == (a.lower() or a.isupper()) or b == (b.isupper() or b.lower()):
    print(0)
elif a != (a.lower() or a.isupper()) or b != (b.isupper() or b.lower()):
    print(-1)
else:
    print(-1)


No entiendo qué tienen que ver las dos etiquetas que pusiste con la pregunta, y la etiqueta del idioma que sería necesaria (asumo que es python), no la pones... no somos adivinos, las etiquetas son útiles para saber a simple vista si nos interesa leer una pregunta o no. Si no pones las etiquetas correctas, la gente que sabe de python nunca verá tu pregunta.

Llevas razón, no me di cuenta, lo tengo en cuenta para la próxima vez!! Gracias.

En lugar de tratar cada posible combinación por separado (letras, mayúsculas, minúscula, números, etc.), anidamos las consultas, para ir refinando las condiciones.
Lo primero es revisar que ambas variables sean letras. Si alguna no lo es, caso resuelto:
if a.isalpha() and b.isalpha():
     # Aqui sólo entramos si ambas son letras.
else:
    print(-1)

Nos queda ver si las letras son del mismo caso. La función upper()/lower() no sirven; sólo convierten el caso. Para ver que caso tiene, se ocupa islower()/isupper().
Las condiciones válidas son:

Ambas mayúsculas: a.isupper() and b.isupper()
Ambas minúsculas: a.islower() and b.islower()

Si cualquiera de las dos se cumple (operación or), imprimimos '1'.
    if a.isupper() and b.isupper() or a.islower() and b.islower():
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)

Conclusión
Poniendo todo junto, queda:
def clasifica(a, b):
    a = input('Introduzca un caracter cualquiera: ')
    b = input('Introduzca otro caracter cualquiera: ')
    
    if a.isalpha() and b.isalpha():
        if a.isupper() and b.isupper() or a.islower() and b.islower():
            print(1)
        else:
            print(0)
    else:
        print(-1)

que luego llamaras con
clasifica()


Muchas gracias!! Aún estoy muy verde en esto, desconocía con un condicional: if podía llevar debajo otro condicional: if. Tomo nota para seguir avanzando!! :)
